# Read property file on both java and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring, jax-ws

I'm using a properties file in project. I want to read the properties file both java and angularjs. suggest me a best location to place the properties file which can accessible by java and also by angularjs.

[image: Here my properties file location]

Comment: "Here my properties file location": where ?

Comment: i draw rect on my properties file location

Comment: Maybe src/main/webapp/prop/yourFile.properties.

Comment: can i read it from java also?

Comment: Yes if your poject is a war packaging file: src/main/webapp is the root of static files so the file src/main/webapp/prop/yourFile.properties whould be accessible in http://yourhost:8080/yourapp/prop/yourFile.properties

Answer (score 0):

By design it should be src/resources folder.

Well by opportunity, it can be placed in webapp too.

Comment: but it not secure. possible to download the property file while place in webapp folder.

Comment: i need to be secure as well as common property file can access by these both

Answer (score 0):

From what I know angularjs is meant to execute on browser. I do not recommend downloading properties into browser as web assets similar to `css/js`. So I would recommend keeping properties in `src/main/resources/`. If you need, host a small rest end point giving these properties as a json map in response. This can be used by angularjs on client side(browser)

Comment: if i place the properties file in the location `src/main/resource/` how can i access through `angularjs`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally properties which have confidential information shoild never be sent to browser.

Any one can get access to those information by debugging in tools like chrome,etc.

Sending such information should not create problems for your system. In those cases you shld hv 2 properties in src/ resources folder. One contains db passwords etc. Other with open information.